# searching result not coming in linked list

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* start = NULL;
void create(struct node*);
void searches(struct node*, int);

void create(struct node* start) {
    node* ptr, newnode;
    int value;
    cout << "enter the data";
    cin >> value;
    while (value != -1) {
        newnode = (struct node)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newnode->data = value;
        if (start == NULL) {
            newnode->next = NULL;
            start = newnode;
        }
        else {
            ptr = start;
            while (ptr->next != NULL)
                ptr = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = newnode;
            newnode->next = NULL;
        }
        cout << "enter the data";
        cin >> value;
    }
}

void searches(struct node* start, int item) {
    struct node* ptr;
    ptr = start;
    while (ptr->next != NULL) {
        if (ptr->data == item) {
            cout << "element is present in a linked list";
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    cout << "element is not present in linked list";
}

int main() {
    int value, option;
    do {
        cout << "\n ************MAIN MENU***************";
        cout << "\n 1. create the list";
        cout << "\n 2. search the element";
        cout << "\n enter your option";
        cin >> option;
        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            create(start);
            cout << "linked list created";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "enter the item which you want to searches in a linked lists";
            cin >> value; searches(start, value);
            cout << "\n search has been done";
            break;
        }
    } while (option != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code when I am choosing option 2 for searching nothing is return. I am not able to check what wrong is done by me in this code.

Comment: If your list has only one element, then `ptr->next != NULL` will always be false.

Comment: I believe it should be `while (ptr != NULL)` in your `searches` function